# create window (with Defining Columns Names and Types) with a context

Tags: esper

I want to use a create window (with Defining Columns Names and Types) with a context. I think that it is possible, because the create window syntaxt allows it. But I have tried to do, and always I have failed. **Any example / help?** thanks in advance.

....The second syntax for creating a named window is by supplying column names and types:

```
*[context context_name]
create window window_name.view_specifications [as] (column_name column_type
[,column_name column_type [,...])*
```

for example

```
create  schema  messageEv   (ipAddress string, userId String, ts long, message string)  ;
create context byIPCtx  Partition By        ipAddress From messageEv ;

context byIPCtx     
create window SecurityEvent.win:time(30 sec) (ipAddress string, userId String, numAttempts in);
```

*Error starting statement: Segmented context requires that any of the event types that are listed in the segmented context also appear in any of the filter expressions of the statement, type 'java.lang.Object' is not one of the types listed*

Comment: Create a window row schema and specify it as part of the context declaration. This way the engine knows what the key-partition association is for the named window row as well. This looks like that:

create  schema  messageEv   (ipAddress string, userId String, ts long, message string)  ;
create  schema  WindowRow   (ipAddress string, userId String, numAttempts in)  ;
create context byIPCtx  Partition By        ipAddress From messageEv, ipAddress From WindowRow ;
context byIPCtx     create window SecurityEvent.win:time(30 sec) as WindowRow;

Answer (score 0):

Check the esper 5.2 online documentation which appears to [have an example](http://www.espertech.com/esper/release-5.2.0/esper-reference/html/context.html#context_named_windows) of your use case.